# PhpStorm IDE 2017.2 does not highlight the error " [] operator not supported for strings" in PHP 7.1.x

Tags: php, phpstorm, php-7.1, incompatibility

I installed PhpStorm version 2017.2 and configured the PHP 7.1 under *Settings > Languages and Frameworks > PHP > PHP Language Level*

Unfortunately it does not highlight possible errors when using the empty array index operator on string variables ( description: http://php.net/manual/de/migration71.incompatible.php#migration71.incompatible.empty-string-index-operator )

Code:

```
<?php
$test = 'a string';

$test[] = 'an array value';

echo "it works";
```

When executing the code with PHP 7.1.x the following error occurs

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in

so the code is definitely not working.

Can anyone help me with the PhpStorm configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug, please vote here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-36636

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. No more answers required.